# Diagnosing Interop call hang on C# desktop app - only for some users

Tags: c#, .net, windows, interop

We have a C# desktop app (*Windows 10 x64*) that is hanging at startup *for a very small number of our users*. I've never seen this before, and I can't reproduce it locally.

Our app uses our C# (managed) library, which includes some Interop calls to our C (native) DLL.
By instrumenting special builds and generous help from users, I've been able to establish that:

- Our managed library is loading OK; I can access classes & static members from our EXE.
- The library contains interop wrappers for a bunch of APIs in our native DLL, and as soon as one of these is called, the app hangs.

This only fails for a few users, this same code has been tested and debugged, and is working fine for thousands of users.

- I've replaced the first, failing Interop call with one that takes no arguments and returns a constant int value -- still freezes.
- I've run DEPENDS.EXE on our DLL and ensured that we're shipping/installing all of the necessary DLL dependencies.
- I've had the affected users run the Visual C++ Redistributable Installer -- no improvement
- The kinds of causes listed above would usually result in the app exiting, but this app hangs without any messagebox or other UI.

**Can anyone offer suggestions as to how this could be diagnosed remotely?**

Comment: I've had issues in the past with an `exe` working on most virtual machines but failing on others, this was very intermittent and was a big pain in the ar$e. I used this tool to help me find the problem: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/getting-started-with-windbg). If you haven't tried it, that may help you.

Comment: Google "c# minidump" to get ahead.  [This hit](https://michaelscodingspot.com/how-to-create-use-and-debug-net-application-crash-dumps-in-2019/) looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a specific 3rd-party DLL that was hanging on load (either CRT startup or DLL main). We did a lot of checking as to the versions of the DLL dependencies, DLL search path, etc. But we never did figure out *exactly* what the issue was; only that a specific DLL (that loaded fine on our systems) would lock up on a tiny percentage of our users' systems.

Solution was to go get a newer build of the DLL(s). That particular set of 3rd-party libraries was built using non-Microsoft tools, so maybe there was some subtle bug in their compiler or linker.